# Custom Report Type on Opportunity Products

Tags: contracts

I have a scenario , please provide inputs.
Our contract is a child of Opportunities.
And i want to report on Product ( specifically ACV ) based on Signed/Activated Contracts.
I cannot use the Standard 'Opportunities with products' report type, because i cannot include Contract fields.
We do have a Lookup to Contracts on Opportunity Products, but it is of no use, because i cannot create a report type based on Contracts -> Opp Products relationship.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you use a CRT where primary object is `Opportunity`, child object is `Opportunity Product`? ... and since, `Opportunity Product` has lookup to `Contract`, you can filter on Opportunities with Products that have activated Contracts

Comment: @cropredy I was excited to see your response, i just tried creating one CRT, and i am not able to select the standard Opportunity Product object (API Name - OpportunityLlineItem). Looks like i can't add a Screenshot here.

Comment: Primary object = Opportunity, child object in the drop down is labeled Products, which in this case are the `Opportunity Products`.  Confusing labeling.

Comment: Ya thanks i can see that now. Appreciate the quick response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

- Create a new Custom Report Type
- Primary object = `Opportunity`
- Child object = `Products` - note, this is really `Opportunity Product`. Were you to select `Product` as a primary object, you are getting the `Product2` object!

When configuring the layout, you can add fields from the Opportunity Products' lookup field `Contract__c` so your report will be able to show fields from the `Contract`.

In your report filter, you can query on Opportunities with Products with signed/activated contracts.  The report will show all products for that opportunity (that is, products without a contract lookup will be included in the results.